# Resizing the completed figure in inkscape

Tags: inkscape

i have made a figure in inkscape and realized that is a landscape orientation with width 608 and height 495. The problem is that i want to make it ready for publication and ideally i want it in portrait orientation and much smaller. I see here in `Document Properties` that the size for A4 is 210x297. Can somebody tell me how i can accomplish this task?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path. Go to Menu.

```
File > Document Properties
```

And you can change the size of your design by setting the custom value in the Custom Size option in Document Properties Window. If you wish you can also change the unit in which you want to work. For your reference, I am attaching a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Or just select A4 from the list above, if that's the size that is needed. For scaling, see https://inkscape-manuals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/selector-tool.html